# Modify existing form Values - GetChoices() not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Why does '[.getChoices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#getChoices())' not work for existing list items?

I have the following code which gets an item in a form by it's ID, and I intend to update the values of the form item. However, when using the .getChoices() method, it fails with the error '*TypeError: Cannot find function getChoices in object Item.*'

The item I'm fetching is a list item as required, and when a list item is created *then* fetched, it works normally as in the sample code listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice#getValue()).

My code is as follows:

```
function getWeekNumberFormItem() {
   var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
   var item = form.getItemById(12345);//redacted for privacy, but the ID in here is correct. 
   var title = item.getTitle();
   var itemType = item.getType();
   Logger.log('Item Type: ' + itemType);
   Logger.log('Item Title: ' + title);
   var choices = item.getChoices();
   Logger.log(choices);
}
```

and to prove it is a list item, my logging output is:

[image]

Am I using this incorrectly, or can this only be used when Apps script creates the item also? How instead would I get the choices in this list item and update them with new options? I see other users have managed to do this, so I believe it's possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Item` is an *interface class* that provides a few methods applicable to all form items. "Interface objects are rarely useful on their own; instead, you usually want to call a method like Element.asParagraph() to cast the object back to a precise class." <sup>[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#dealing_with_interfaces)</sup>

Since `.getChoices()` is a method that belongs to the [`ListItem`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item.html) class, and does not appear in `Item`, you need to cast your `Item` to `ListItem` using [`Item.asListItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asListItem()).

```js
...
var itemType = item.getType();

if (itemType == FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {

  var choices = item.asListItem().getChoices();
  //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
else throw new Error( "Item is not a List." );
```

Comment: This worked, but seems like it's badly documented, or am I just missing something in the documentation?

Comment: The use of a generic object that can be specialized like this is a common pattern in object oriented javascript, and it appears in GAS in several places. The 'ref' above describes it briefly, and you'll see it in [DocumentApp.element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) and the first [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) example. Most of the docs are an API guide - more about what is available than how you can use it to solve specific problems. If it matches the way you approach problems, it's not bad.

Comment: Just saved me a sleepless night.