# Creating a form based upon missing data from google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data set in google sheets that has some missing info in certain fields. All the data is uniform under certain headings and all have a unique ID value. I have created a validation sheet which pulls the missing field's corresponding unique ID value and its column header to know what items are missing, but I wanted to create a google form to be created based upon these missing values.

The amount of missing cells would be the amount of unique ID's yielded from the validation sheet.

[Google-sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VXabkCMp5pVom-K5swk1wgfTCXBXEj4VUl1tAFDcW1U/edit?usp=sharing) 
Explanation of sheets:

**Raw Data** is just that.

**ValidationSheet** clears out any filled in cells and provides the corresponding ID in column A

**Non-Blank(Query)** and **Non-Blank(Formula)** both condense the ValidationSheet data (both do the same thing just one has a formula other uses query)

**Unpivot** is an unpivoted result of the Non-Blank sheets.

*The intent is to create a form based on the Unpivoted values where the form has the unique ID populated, the field that is missing as a question for them to fill in the blank.*

The code I have tried is only half complete as I'm not sure of the following steps

```
function createForm() {

  var item = "Missing Data"

  var form = FormApp.Create(item)
  .setTitle(item);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ResponseSheet);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var responses = form.getResponses();


  item = (Define item to be the missing value)
  form.addTextItem()
     .setTitle(<insert missing value here & add more text saying "missing value">)
     .setRequired(true);
```

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information) including both the complete dataset as well as the "missing data" dataset. Would you please edit your question to advise i) how many records are in the "missing field" dataset, ii) how many fields per record are missing, and iii) what are the characteristics of each missing field?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz thanks for the reply. My question has been updated to reflect this as well as including a link to the sheets and a brief overview of the sheets

Comment: I have a question about process. Will you have circulated a list (perhaps from the spreadsheet) so that users know the details and location of the respective equipment that has a missing field. For example, ID 3531158 is missing a "Mark", but it would be inadequate if the form merely required input of the ID and Mark without confirmation that the unit is a pump, in room such-and-such, Brand, model, etc

Comment: There are 2,100+ records on "Rawdata" but only 20 items on "Unpivot". Do you anticipate 20 forms or one form?  There is an interesting topic [remove selected items from google form dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303565/1330560)-answered by highly qualified users. In addition, Forms allows each dropdown to be routed to a specific section; so... it IS possible to have a single form comprising a dropdown section and sections for "Room", "Maintenance" and "Mark". This form can be built manually; its just a question of how to built it programmatically ;)

Comment: Would you please provide feedback about whether you want many individual forms, or one-mega form, or one conditional logic do-all form? From several sources, including [Modify existing form Values - GetChoices not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359531/1330560), [google script forms ListItem: how to set pageBreakItems for each choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098802/1330560), I have established a methodology for the code - but it does depend on the strategy that you want to take.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, thanks for the replies. I had a review over the weekend of the best methodology so it can be a dynamic solution for any upcoming events. 
I think a conditional logic-do all form would be the best solution as it would save needing to send out and handle so many different forms if there would be over 100 missing values. I think there could be additional fields that can be entered which would help filtering the response i.e by manufacturer.
The intention is to then have the missing raw data input into a combining spreadsheet looking for the key of the unique ID and the missing field

Comment: Is it possible/likely that, from time-to-time, there would be more than one missing field for an ID/Tag record?

Comment: There is a challenge with the "do-all conditional logic form" - in the event that there is more than one field missing for a given ID/Tag, it is not as simple as directing to one question but rather (I think) directing to a specific page (and populating that page with the relevant questions). In any event, while working on this, I found an excellent YouTube resource that addresses the importing of spreadsheet data to the Form.[Google Forms - Drop Down List from Spreadsheet Using Apps Script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3AL7ASI_cA) by http://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com. Recommended.

Comment: That youtube video was brilliant! I'll definitely see about creating a form from what is described in the video to see if might be any different. It's a little tricky to figure out the best workflow at the moment but will provide an update from tomorrow. Thanks @Tedinoz

Comment: Refer my adjusted answer - this is the full working system

Answer (score 0):

### Provided your validation sheet looks like this:

[image]

### Here is how you can create forms based on missing data:

```
function createForm() {

  var title = "Missing Data";  //changed
  var ResponseSheet="Sheet1"; //replace with your sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ResponseSheet);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headings=data[0];  //provided that your headings are stored in the first row
  for(var i=1; i<data.length;i++){
    var item=[];
    for (var j=1; j<headings.length;j++){
      if(data[i][j]==""||data[i][j]==" "){
        item[j]=headings[j];
      } 
    } 
    if(!item.length == 0){
      var form = FormApp.create(headings[0])  //Careful! It's create and not Create
       .setTitle("Form submission "+data[i][0]+" "+ title);
      item.forEach(function(element) {
      form.addTextItem()
      .setTitle(element+" missing value")
      .setRequired(true);
      })               
      Logger.log("Form submission "+data[i][0]+": "+form.getPublishedUrl());
    }
  }
}
```

> This approach is based on the assumption that you have several form
>   submissions with missing data, so a new "Missing Data" form will be
>   created in response to each submission with missing data.

### Idea:

You loop through all cells of a row and if you find at least one empty one - you create a form for this row and append to it as form items the column headings corresponding to the empty cells.

### Result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi there @ziganotschka , thanks for the reply. That is close to what I need but I have realised I can condense a lot of the work down by removing the blank cells prior to the form creation by using a query function (google sheet link now in question). The form requires to be made inclusive of the ID so the respondent is aware of the item they need to input data in but I will continue to develop on what you have provided. Thanks

Comment: So do you want a single form which contains all missing values retrieved from Unpivot as textItems?

Answer (score 0):

There are usually many ways of doing things in Google Scripts - this scenario is no exception. Please regard this as merely one way of achieving an outcome.

This code is written in the script editor attached to the spreadsheet.

**Overview**
A Google Form that enables update of Drop-down options for a ListItem from data in a spreadsheet.
The drop-down options are in Question 1, and each item automatically is linked to the relevant Page/Question based on the spreadsheet data.
The design assumes that each drop-down has only one subsequent question (though a more complex system could be built).

The code consists of several functions, but it works as a system.
Therefore there are a number of specific steps required to initiate and manage the Form.

These are:
**A - CREATE THE SPREADSHEET AND FORM - a manual process.**

- Create a spreadsheet, or use an existing spreadsheet to contain information about missing.
- Create a form in your chosen Drive folder and with an appropriate file name (you can change these later if you wish). It's preferable to create a new form so that all the changes are driven by the code.

**B - COPY THE CODE TO THE SPREADSHEET - a manual process.**

- Open the Spreadsheet Scrip Editor.
- Create a suitable project name if one doesn't already exist.
- Create a new script file (with appropriate name).
- Copy ALL the code included below into the script file.
- Save the script file.

**C - UPDATE GLOBAL VARIABLES - a manual process.**
In the Spreadsheet script editor, update the Global Variables at the top of the script file.

- Enter the Spreadsheet ID = "insert spreadsheet ID"
- Enter the Form ID = "insert form ID"
- Enter the sheet (tab) name (NOT the name of file/Spreadsheet) where the missing field information will be recorded
- Save the script file.

**D - UPDATE THE SPREADSHEET.**

- If the sheet doesn't already exist, create it.
- Enter/confirm the column headings for the sheet
  // Headers should be in row#1; data starting in Row#2
  // Column headings are:
  // Column A - Unique ID
  // Column B - Tag Number
  // Column C - Missing data field
  // FYI: the current list of "possible" fields is: Room Number, Type Mark, Description, Mark, Manufacturer, Model, Warranty End Date, Date Installed, Maintenance.
  // If new fields are created, or existing fields deleted/changed, then it will be necessary to also update information manually.

**E - INSTALL THE INSTALLABLE TRIGGER**

In the Spreadsheet script editor, click the "clock" icon to install an "Installable" trigger.

- Add Trigger.
- Function to Run = "sheetOpen"
- Runs at Deployment = "Head" (default)
- Select Event Source = Spreadsheet (default)
- Select Event Type = On open
- Click Save.
  You may be asked to confirm permissions, complete this as usual.
- Close the spreadsheet and open it again - there's now a custom menu "Missing Fields Form"

**CUSTOM MENU ("Missing Fields Form")**
1 - Initial setup (repeatable)
2 - Add Missing Field Sections and Questions (once only)
3 - Create form destination (repeatable)
4 - Build the content for specific ids and missing fields (repeatable)

**INITIAL SETUP**
From the custom menu, select "Inital Setup"
This updates the following values:

- Title
- Description
- Confirmation Message
- Allow users to edit their responses: No
- Enable for the form to accept response: True

You can modify the initial settings settings and run this function as often as you wish. It also creates a new Drop-down question. If the drop down exists, then it won't create a second copy; if the drop-down does NOT exist, then it will be created.

**ADD MISSING FIELD SECTIONS AND QUESTIONS (once only)**
This will add a new section and question for every field possibility.

**CREATE FORM DESTINATION**
From the custom menu, select "Create new Form Destination" 
This creates a new destination sheet in the spreadsheet for Form Responses.

**BUILD THE CONTENT FOR SPECIFIC IDs AND MISSING FIELDS**
This takes the Unique IDs and their Missing Fields from the Spreadsheet and adds them to the Drop-Down List.
Each item is automatically linked to the relevant Page.
This procedure can be totally repeatable and can be done as many times as the user may wish.
Any/all IDs and Fields in the Form will be overwritten by the data in the spreadsheet.

---

```
// This code is designed to manage a form for collecting information about missing fields in a Plant Register.
// This version of the code is designed for the scenario where there is only ONE missing data field per equipment item record

// Global variables

// Record the ID of the spreadsheet
var ssID = "1-DDTt_dEV2LLtGwhZ6qBtGHrz07EJ4Ef4yxxuZKaEF8";
// Record the ID of the form
var formID = "1MJYof24YrUubpdFBlxT63LSVpvshh4eFKaUQGITlBms";
// Record the sheet (tab) name where the missing data will be recorded (starting in cell A1
// column headings for that sheet are:
// Column A - Unique ID
// Column B - Tag Number
// Column C - MIssing data field
var sheetname = "form_input_single";
// open the spreadsheet
var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName(sheetname);
// open the form
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);


/*
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
*/


    // The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded    
    // Add a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, including a separator and a sub-menu.    
    // Adds the custom menu to the active spreadsheet.
    function sheetOpen() {

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Missing Fields Form')
        .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Setup')
          .addItem('1: Inital Setup (repeatable)', 'formsetup')
          .addItem(
            '2: Add Missing Field Sections and Questions (once only)',
            'addMissingfieldsandPagebreaks')
          .addItem('3. Create new Form Destination (repeatable)',
            'setFormdestination'))
        .addSeparator()
        .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(
            'Update Missing Fields')
          .addItem(
            '4. Build the content for specific PLANT IDs and respective missing fields (repeatable)',
            'UpdateDropDownItems'))
        .addToUi();
    }


    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */

    //Step#1
    function formsetup() {
      // Update form properties via chaining.
      form.setTitle('Equipment Register Update')
        .setDescription(
          'This form is used to complete missing fields in the Equipment Register'
          )
        .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
        .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
        .setAcceptingResponses(true);

      // Build the initial Drop-down question
      buildInitialDropdownQuestion();

      // Add the Missing field drop-downs items ands links
      //addDropDownItems();
    }

    function buildInitialDropdownQuestion() {

      // Build
      // list ListItems
      var listitems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
      if (listitems.length != 0) {
        Logger.log("DEBUG: These are the list items");
        for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
          Logger.log("DEBUG:" + listitems[i].getTitle() + ", ID= " +
            listitems[i].getId());
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("DEBUG: there are no list items");
        // add opening list item and Title
        var item = form.addListItem();
        item.setTitle('Tag/Equipment Number');
        item.setRequired(true);
      }
    }

    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */
    // Step#2  
    function addMissingfieldsandPagebreaks() {

      // add all the potential missing fields and relevant questions
      // as built, this is intended to run once only. 
      // If this function is run more than once, it will duplicate the existing pages and questions

      // Equipment - Mark
      var mark = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
        "The Mark on the equipment?").setHelpText(
        'Updating identifying marks on equipment').setGoToPage(FormApp
        .PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Mark").setHelpText(
        '(an identifying mark on the equipment)').setRequired(true);

      // Room Number
      var roomnumber = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
        "The Rooom number?").setHelpText(
        'Updating the room number for this equipment').setGoToPage(
        FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Room Number").setHelpText(
        '(format XX-ZZZZ)').setRequired(true);

      // Maintenance
      var maintenance = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
        "Maintenance Schedule").setHelpText(
        'Updating the maintenance schedule').setGoToPage(FormApp
        .PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
        .setTitle('Maintenance')
        .setChoiceValues(['6 monthly', '12 Monthly', 'As required',
          'N/A'])
        .showOtherOption(false)
        .setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Type Mark
      var typemark = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
        "The Type Mark on the equipment?").setHelpText(
        'Updating equipment type marks').setGoToPage(FormApp
        .PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Type Mark").setHelpText(
        '(an identifying Type Mark on the equipment)').setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Description
      var description = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
        "Describe the equipment").setHelpText(
        'Updating the description of an item of equipment').setGoToPage(
        FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Description").setHelpText(
        '(Equipment type and specification)').setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Manufacturer
      var manufacturer = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
          "Name of the Manufacturer").setHelpText(
          'Updating the manufacturer name for an item of equipment')
        .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Manufacturer").setHelpText('(Name)')
        .setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Model
      var model = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle("Model Name")
        .setHelpText('Updating the Model Number for an item of equipment')
        .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addTextItem().setTitle("Model").setHelpText('(Name)')
        .setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Warranty End Date
      var warrantyenddate = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
          "Warranty End Date").setHelpText(
          'Updating the Warranty End-Date for an item of equipment')
        .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addDateItem().setTitle("Warranty End Date").setHelpText(
        '(dd/mm/yyyy)').setRequired(true);

      // Equipment - Date Installed
      var dateinstalled = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(
          "Installation date").setHelpText(
          'Updating the Installation date for an item of equipment')
        .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);;
      form.addDateItem().setTitle("Date Installed").setHelpText(
        '(dd/mm/yyyy)').setRequired(true);

    }

    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */
    // Step#3
    function setFormdestination() {

      // Update the form's response destination.
      form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ssID);
    }
    /*
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    */

    // Step#4
    function UpdateDropDownItems() {

      // build the content of the Drop-down item, together with links to relevant questions/pages
      // This can be run as many times as neccessary.

      var ddid = getdropdownid(); // as an integer
      var plantList = form.getItemById(ddid).asListItem();

      var pagebreaks = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK);

      var LR = wsData.getLastRow();
      var dataRange = wsData.getRange(2, 1, LR - 1, 3);
      var values = dataRange.getValues();
      var valLen = values.length;


      var newchoices = [];;

      for (var v = 0; v < valLen; v++) {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: v:"+v+", field: "+values[v][2]);
        var pb = getpbid(values[v][2]); //as an integer
        // Logger.log(values[v][2]+" = "+pb);

        var pbitem = form.getItemById(pb).asPageBreakItem();

        var dropdown = values[v][0] + " - " + values[v][
        1]; //Concatenate the Unique ID and the Equipment Number
        newchoices.push(plantList.createChoice(dropdown,
        pbitem)); // push create choice onto array

      }
      plantList.setChoices(newchoices);

    }

    function getdropdownid() {
      // Utility
      // get the ID for the Listitem 
      // called by UpdateDropDownItems()

      // list List Items
      var listitems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
      var item = listitems[0];
      var listitemid = item.getId().toString();
      //Logger.log(listitemid)
      //Logger.log(item.getId().toString());
      return listitemid;

    }

    function getpbid(title) {

      // Utility
      // get the page break ID; called by UpdateDropDownItems()
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: getpbid - title attribute:"+title) 
      var pagebreaks = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK);
      var titles = pagebreaks.map(function(pagebreak) {
        return pagebreak.getTitle();
      });
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: titles = "+titles)
      var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: posn = "+pos);
      var pagebreak = pagebreaks[pos];
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: pagebreak:"+pagebreak);
      var pagebreakID = pagebreak.getId();
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: pagebreakID:"+pagebreakID);
      return pagebreakID;

    }
```

---

Spreadsheet layout
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

---

Dropdowns showing page link
[image: Dropdowns showing page link]

---